Kryo Deserialization results in data corruption issues if target DTO class is modified,
We've identified data corruption during DTO deserialization when there are changes in existing fields/instance variables in a dto
To Reproduce
Have a simple dto, lets say employee with following details
public class Employee{
   private String name;
    private long age;
    private String company;
}

Serialize this dto using below code
Output outK3 = new Output(new FileOutputStream("rename.bin"))
kryo.writeObject(out, employee);
 outK3.close();

Change the dto
public class Employee{
  private String name;
   private short xge;
   private String company;
}

De-Serialize now using below code
Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream("rename.bin"));
       try {
           Employee k = kryo.readObject(input, s.getClass());
           System.out.println("Kryo 5 Test" + k);
           input.close();

Expected Behaviour
Since the dto has changes , kryo should either throw an exception or should give the correct data but we are seeing data corruption , example below
Kryo 5 TestEmployee{firstName='Abcde', age=36, company='Kronos'}  --- Original
Kryo 5 TestEmployee{firstName='Abcde', age=19272, company='ronos'}  -- -- After De-Serializing
Environment:
OS: Windows
JDK Version: 8
Kryo Version: 5.6.0
